# Alter form preloading

Tags: 7, entities

I'm trying to remove id's from entity reference autocomplete fields but i got stuck at the initialization of a form where the default value is set to the user name , not the name of the profile2. I've successfully removed the id's when the user changes values but after it hits save the value is set back to user name and the id. What function should i override in entity reference module to be able to change the behavior of the autocomplete field ?